# bitstring to decimal integer conversion

Tags: parsing, binary, elixir, decimal, phoenix-framework

I have a bitstring of 4 bytes. I want the equivalent decimal number in elixir `<<91, 84, 107, 24>>`. This bitstring is basically a representation of epoch `1532259096`. I googled a lot and could not find something useful related to this in elixir.

Note: Ultimately I want datetime object from this, if I can skip converting to number thats wonderful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the binary pattern `<<n::32>>` to extract a big endian 32 bit unsigned integer from a 4 byte binary:

```
iex(1)> <<n::32>> = <<91, 84, 107, 24>>
<<91, 84, 107, 24>>
iex(2)> n
1532259096
```